# Update my AWS EB Node.js to version 6.0.0

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there anyway to push my EB instance to run a later node.js version, the docs here say that the supported platform version is only 4.4.3 but I need to run 6.0.0

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.nodejs

Comment: Not really, using a PAAS layer you need to stick with what the provider gives you - you can still run your app on EC2 and install any version you need but you will need to manage the server

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but it's going to require a bit more configuration/work than simply changing a select box, and it may increase the amount of time it takes for your containers to launch, depending on what route you take to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html#command-options-nodejs) it seems that only some versions are supported on Elastic Beanstalk (mainly 4.4.3 / 0.12.6 but not 6.0.0). You can still choose between these versions in the interface but not outside this list.

The only solution I see for now is to deploy your own stack directly on an EC2 instance without using the Elastic Beanstalk service.